# Repair Windows 7 MBR with Hiren's Boot CD

Tags: windows-7, mbr

I would like to repair my Windows 7 MBR using Hiren's Boot CD 15.1.

I want to know the generic method, using this CD, to fix an MBR that is hypothetically "toast".

This hypothetical HD is as follows:

- 100 MB MBR partition
- 60 GB Windows 7 system

Let's imagine there is an empty 100 MB partition and the MBR is corrupt beyond repair or completely not there and my only option is Hiren's Boot CD.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Hirens has the [MbrFix tool](https://web.archive.org/web/20120113034306/http://www.sysint.no/nedlasting/mbrfix.htm).

example:

> C:> MbrFix /drive 0 fixmbr /yes

[MBRtool](https://web.archive.org/web/20120530003038/http://www.diydatarecovery.nl/MBRtool_manual.htm) is also on the Hirens disc

Comment: There is a really nice video of how you do this here:http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bd73hV0audU

Comment: Does this work on UEFI systems?

Comment: UEFI does not use a MBR, so no.

Comment: Links in this answer is not available, Please update

Comment: @PreshanPradeepa fixed as best I could.

Comment: This answer save me a lot of time, but I guess you forgot to mention the parameter `/win7`.
I think the command should be `MbrFix /drive 0 fixmbr /win7 /yes`
AFAIK this should work on win7 but also on 8 and 10.